# rdlc report shows blank when multi-valued-parameter is set

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm trying to display field values in comma separated using multi valued report parameter with below expression, but report itself is showing blank.

```
="all values" & JOIN(Parameters!ReportParameter2.Label)
```

---

I've dataset named 'Sessions' having fields as below -

```
Id, typeof(int)
MeetingId, typeof(int)
SessionType, typeof(string)
```

---

I created multi valued report parameter in RDLC as below -
**General**:
    Name: ReportParameter2
    Data type : Text
    Allow multiple values: checked

**Available values**:
    Get values from a query : radio button checked
    Dataset: Sessions
    Value field: Id
    Label field: SessionType

**Default values**:
    Get values from a query : radio button checked
    Dataset: Sessions
    Value field: Id

---

My code in .aspx.cs, button click event as follows -

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("MeetingId", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("SessionType", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(1, 1, "case1");
table.Rows.Add(2, 1, "case2");

datasource = new ReportDataSource("Sessions", table);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
```

---

My code in .aspx, as follows -

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" 
namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" AsyncRendering="true"
    Style="width:100%;height:700px;"
    OnReportError="ReportViewer1_ReportError"></rsweb:ReportViewer>  

<asp:Button OnClick="CaseList_Click" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="CaseList" />

</form>
```

From last 2 days I'm working on this issue, please help me..

Comment: Not sure what that top line of code is, but shouldn't there be a space to separate `all values` from the 1st item in the join? Maybe show what that represents and what that `Parameters!ReportParameter2.Label` even consists of.

Comment: Hi Charles, forget about that line, report shows blank after creating 'ReportParameter2' with default value as 'no value' or using 'Get values from a query', but it will show if I set default value using 'specify values' option..